# Echo and Print statement

Tags: php

Suppose the following code:

```
<?php
echo 'hello' . print 123;
```

is executed.

What I expect is `hello123`, but the actual output is `123hello1`.

Why does 123 come first? And why does the output contain `1` at the end?

(I also tried to put a pair of parenthesis around `hello`, but still the same result.)

Comment: Sorry. I am not asking for solutions to this problem. What I want is explanation. Thanks your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
echo 'hello' . print 123;
```

This concatenates `'hello'` with the *return value* of `print 123`. Before `print` *returns* the value `1`, it *outputs* `123`. The concatenated `hello1` is *output* afterwards by `echo`. So the evaluation is:

1. output `123`
2. return `1`
3. concatenate `'hello'` and `1`
4. output `hello1`.

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php#refsect1-function.print-returnvalues) clearly says that, `print` function will return 1 always.

So here how it goes.

Execution of print function -> Output `123` -> return `1` -> concat with `hello` .

Answer (score 1):

The return value of [print](http://php.net/print) is always **1**.

Your code has a concatenation dot character:

```
'hello' . print 123;
```

So all parts are evaluated before concatenation:

- 'hello' is 'hello'
- print 123 : it displays '123' on the screen, and returns 1

Then the echo displays the evaluated string:

```
echo 'hello'.'1' // '1' is the return value of print
```

The final string printed on the string is `123hello1`.

Answer (score 0):

Why does 123 come first?
Probably because the print statement gets executed first and prints '123' as it should.

And why does the output contain 1 at the end?
Because 'print' returns 1, and your echo statement echo's that '1'